# Eclipse Subversive - change a previous commit message

Tags: eclipse, svn, message, commit, subversive

I was wondering if there was a way to change an already committed message through Eclipse's Subversive Plugin.  I'm currently using Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 with Subversive SVN Team Provider 2.0

This is the error I get when I try to Edit the svn:log

```
SVN: 'Set revision property' operation finished with error: svn: E175002: DAV request failed; it's possible that the repository's pre-revprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent
svn: E175002: Error setting property log:
Repository has not been enabled to accept revision propchanges;
ask the administrator to create a pre-revprop-change hook
svn: E175002: DAV request failed; it's possible that the repository's pre-revprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent
svn: E175002: Error setting property log:
Repository has not been enabled to accept revision propchanges;
ask the administrator to create a pre-revprop-change hook
```

I followed this blog post: http://slopjong.de/2010/01/20/let-svn-accept-revision-propchanges/

I edited the 'pre-revprop-change.tmpl' file inside the repository's *hooks* folder, changing the suffix to .bat, but Eclipse says that .bat is not a recognized Win32 file (couldn't get the error message to stay displayed for some reason to post the full error message).  I changed it anyways to .bat.

This is the current contents of the file:

> REPOS="$1" REV="$2" USER="$3" PROPNAME="$4" ACTION="$5"
>
> if [ "$ACTION" = "M" -a "$PROPNAME" = "svn:log" ]; then exit 0; fi
>
> echo "Changing revision properties other than svn:log is prohibited"
>   
> >&2 exit 1

I changed it to:

```
@echo off
exit /B 0
```

as the blog post suggested, but I still get the error trying to change the commit message.

What I noticed in the original script also is that it says "Changing revision properties other than svn:log is prohibited" and the if statement that exits with 0 based on that.  svn:log is the only property I wish to change which is the commit message itself, so I'm wondering why the error popups in the first place.

These are the steps I take to edit svn:log:

*Navigator - Right click on Folder or **File** > **Team** > **Show History** > right click **revision #** > **Show Revision Properties** > Right click **svn:log** > **Edit** > Change message inside property value **textarea***

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: It seems you have an apache httpd serving your Repository? So it should be not related to eclipse at all, as the server(httpd) is complaining, not your client(subversive).
Where lies your "project's hooks folder? I wonder that you are working on your server. Are you the administrator of your repository?

Comment: @PeterParker Thanks for the reply.  I'm not sure what apache has to do with my repository.  I'm using slik SVN, and yes I should be the administrator for the repository as it's my account repo.  I have a repo project folder that I checked out from the 'SVN Repository Exploring', then several project folders within it.  I think I see a possible issue, the hooks folder is under a 'repo' folder inside the repository project folder.  Maybe it should be inside the actual project folder?  Should I update the question with the hooks folder location? Thanks.

Comment: @Ikisac. No the hooks folder _must_be inside your repository, as changing your commit message is an operation performed on your repository, not your project folder(working copy). I was just asking because it was not clear if you were talking about your repo or your projet folder

Comment: @PeterParker  ah, I did say projects folder in the question.  I'll edit that, so it's more clear thanks!  Any idea as to how to allow changes to the commit message?  Although I'm still wondering why it's not allowed in the first place based on the pre-revprop-change.tmpl  script..

Comment: if you have an executable file(.bat for windows) returning 0 in your repo's hooks folder it should work. Did you test another SVN client?

Comment: @PeterParker  I only have the slikSVN client at the moment, I guess I could make a new one.  Which client would you recommend?  I guess any just for testing purposes?  I'm wondering if the error '.bat is not a valid Win32 application' Eclipse is giving me might be a problem.  I made the .bat file in Eclipse by creating a new file under the hooks folder, should I be writing the .bat file somewhere else?  If that makes any difference..